# php GET request is not working as expected

Tags: php

My server code:

```
<?php

$temp = $_GET["emailData"];
  if($temp != ''){
    echo "YEAAAAAAAAAAAA";
  }

?>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#EMAIL').click(function(){
  console.log(sendDATA[0]);
$.post("indexSMS.php", {emailData: sendDATA[0]}, function(response){

 if ( response == 'success' ) {
    // do something
   } else {
// do something else
  }
     });
});
```

It's day one for me with php. Nothing seems to be happening in the php file. Where will the `echo` output be visible. How do I send the response back? 
Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: You're sending a POST request, but accessing a GET variable. Use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`.

Comment: What @Blender said. And everything echoed out in your php file will be stored in the `response` variable.

Comment: some people consider the ability to copy and paste 'learning'

Comment: @web2students.com I am a front end developer, need to get the mailgun api working, sat through w3 schools - basic stuff, sorry i took the learn by diving in approach and this functionality is what was wanted. I know programming constructs so thought may be this can be pulled off

Comment: @Blender so for every get / post request il need separate <?php   some code ?> blocks

Comment: @tussh13: Before you go any further, do you know the difference between a GET and a POST request?

Comment: @Blender yes I know now, get appends query to the url with a max length of 2000 chars, sorry for the blunder in the post. The confusion always was the response bit, the get bit was a typo.

Answer (score 3):

You are sending a a post request so you should use `$_POST` instead of `$_GET`

```
$temp = $_POST["emailData"];
if($temp != ''){
    echo "YEAAAAAAAAAAAA";
}
```